# Joomla wrapper improving meta data

Tags: php, iframe, joomla, metadata, wrapper

Our website uses joomla 1.5 and wrapper to pull in and compile pages. This means that it has duplicate metadata. Here is an example from the site

http://www.ifootpath.com/index.php?option=com_wrapper&view=wrapper&Itemid=39&walkID=3048

Is there a way I can write the meta data to each page pulling form the database so that it improves the SEO? I am aware that wrapper/iFrame pages perform poorly with respect to SEO.

Or am I wasting my time trying to do this?

Many thanks

Comment: Are you saying you actually could have the metadata from the wrapped content stored? (I guess because the content itself is pretty fixed?) In that case yet.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and apologies for not replying before. Yes I would like each page  - there are 500 of them to have different meta data  - perhaps pulled from the page title, description, etc.

Comment: So you want the metadata from the wrapped pages? I think you would have to scrape their rendered page unless you have access to their database. You could page scrape but it violates the terms of service for some sites. You could also just store it when you make the menu links.

Comment: It's my database. It is generating  the wrapper pages from a database that holds all the info and sits on our server. I did not build the site (ad I am learning Joomla) We also have two apps connected that pull the same data.

Comment: You (or someone) could write a system plugin to query the other database and add the desired metadata to the head.  Your site always makes me want to get on a plane and go to England to do some walking.

Comment: That sounds like a good answer. I will look for someone who can do that for me.